# android studio shows no errors but the code crashes

Tags: java, android

i am new to android studio and java so pleas make the sentences simple.
since i am new to this i wanted to create an easy program such as a calculator(2nd program).
The code is:

```
package com.example.mikus.calc;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static int task = 0;
    private static String in1 = "0";
    private static String in2 = "0";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt1);
        Button bt2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt2);
        Button bt3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt3);
        Button bt4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt4);
        Button bt5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt5);
        Button bt6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt6);
        Button bt7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt7);
        Button bt8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt8);
        Button bt9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt9);
        Button bt0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt0);
        Button btdot = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btdot);
        Button btdevide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btdevide);
        Button bttimes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bttimes);
        Button btminus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btminus);
        Button btplus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btplus);
        Button btequals = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btequals);
        final TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);


        bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String text = txt.getText() + "1";
                txt.setText(text);
            }
        });

        bt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String text = txt.getText() + "2";

                txt.setText(text);
            }
        });

        bt3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String text = txt.getText() + "3";

                txt.setText(text);
            }
        });

        bt4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String text = txt.getText() + "4";

                txt.setText(text);
            }
        });

        bt5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String text = txt.getText() + "5";

                txt.setText(text);
            }
        });

        bt6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String text = txt.getText() + "6";

                txt.setText(text);
            }
        });

        bt7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String text = txt.getText() + "7";

                txt.setText(text);
            }
        });

        bt8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String text = txt.getText() + "8";

                txt.setText(text);
            }
        });

        bt9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String text = txt.getText() + "9";

                txt.setText(text);
            }
        });

        bt0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String text = txt.getText() + "0";

                txt.setText(text);
            }
        });

        btdot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String text = txt.getText() + ".";

                txt.setText(text);
            }
        });

        btequals.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int a = Integer.parseInt(in1);
                in2 = txt.getText().toString();
                int b = Integer.parseInt(in2);
                if(task == 1){
                    txt.setText(a + b);
                }
                if(task == 2){
                    txt.setText(a - b);
                }
                if(task == 3){
                    txt.setText(a * b);
                }
                if(task == 4){
                    txt.setText(a / b);
                }
            }
        });

        btplus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                task = 1;
                in1 = txt.getText().toString();
                txt.setText("");
            }
        });

        btminus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                task = 2;
                in1 = txt.getText().toString();
                txt.setText("");
            }
        });

        bttimes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                task = 3;
                in1 = txt.getText().toString();
                txt.setText("");
            }
        });


        btdevide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                task = 4;
                in1 = txt.getText().toString();
                txt.setText("");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

i compile it in my android studio and it has no errors and i run it on my phone and when i press equals it just crashes.(i am trying only adding. and don`t tell that i would not be able to to add decimals to integer or division would not be precise or something else). by the way there are no mistakes on which button corresponds to what name. the layout is almoast the same as the default calculator on phone. bt stands for button and the number or name describes what the button is or what it does in the

Comment: please post the log cat  also try doing  `String text = txt.getText().toString() + "1";`

Comment: why should adding .toString() change anything because + "1" should indicate to java that it is dealing with a string type so it converts the gotten text from txt.getText() to a string type. Post a comment if i am wrong about anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write:

```
txt.setText(String.valueOf(a + b));
```

Then you'll get the string value of your equation, and can set is as the text in the TextView.

Comment: Thanks this did solve the problem. So i guess it can only output a string type to the screen not integer.

Comment: No problem. The setText() method accepts a string as a parameter, and as you were passing an integer, it fails. Therefore a convertion was needed.